# CASE statement not running both WHENs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case

I am having a query problem. **(I go into much more detail at the bottom of the post)** I have a table of checkboxes. I send the checked boxes to a PHP file on POST to update the `db`.  The only way I could figure out if there was a previously `checked` box that got unchecked before the `POST` was to query what should've been checked in the table and if it wasn't sent via `POST` then it had been unchecked. I decided to handle all this in one query. For some reason, though, it isn't handling the unchecked. If I check one **Not** previosuly checked then it will stay checked (It will mark it as checked in the `db`) However, if I uncheck one that was previously checked it will stay checked (I want it to uncheck it).

Here is my code for creating the checkboxes:

```
echo "<table class='tables' border='1'>";   //start an HTML table

    $fields =array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT u.unit_nickname AS unit, r.id AS reservation,
                                CONCAT(g.fname,' ',g.lname) AS guest, r.arrival, r.departure,
                                r.total_price - COALESCE(p.payment_amt, 0) AS balance,
                                r.checked_in 
                                FROM reservations r
                                JOIN units u ON r.unit = u.id 
                                JOIN guests g ON r.guest = g.id LEFT JOIN
                                (SELECT reservation, SUM(payment_amt) payment_amt
                                FROM payments
                                GROUP BY reservation) AS p
                                ON r.id = p.reservation
                                WHERE r.checked_out = 0");  

    echo '<th></th><th>Unit</th><th>Reservation</th><th>Guest</th><th>Arrival</th>
        <th>Depart</th><th>Balance</th><th>Status</th>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {       
        $fields[] = $row['unit']; $fields[] = $row['reservation']; $fields[] = $row['guest'];
        $fields[] = $row['arrival']; $fields[] = $row['departure']; $fields[] = $row['balance'];
        $fields[] = $row['checked_in'];

        //rowid == id of table (the row corresponds to the row in the table)
        $rowid = $row['reservation'];

        $count = count($fields);

        echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$fields[1]."' name='checkins[]'"; 
        if ($row['checked_in'] == 1)
            echo "checked='yes'";
        echo "/></td>"; 

        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {
            echo "<td><span id='".$fields[1]."'>", ($j+1 == $count ? ($fields[$j] == 0 ? "Not Checked In" : "Checked In") : "".$fields[$j]."");
            echo "</span></td>"; 
        }

        echo "</tr>";

        //empty array
        $fields = "";
    }

    echo "</table>";    //close the HTML table
```

Here is part of my PHP file that it's submitting to:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkins']))
{
    //open connection
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    //set POST to array
    $checkins = array();

    //get all checkins that are not checked out
    $query = "SELECT id FROM reservations WHERE checked_in = 1 AND checked_out = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $checkedins[] = $row;

    //create WHERE clause for new checkins
    $where = " WHERE id =";
     foreach ($_POST['checkins'] as $id) {
        $where .= " $id OR id =";
        array_push($checkins, $id);
    }

    //loop through $checkedins[]
    foreach ($checkedins as $id) {
        //if they were checked in before and are now not checked in, add to list
        if (!in_array($id["id"], $checkins))
            $where .= " ".$id['id']." OR id =";
    }

    //remove last 8 characters from WHERE clause
    $where = substr($where, 0, -8);

    echo $query = "UPDATE reservations
                SET checked_in = CASE 
                WHEN checked_in = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN checked_in = 1 THEN 0 END 
                $where";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I have tried to comment well enough to explain what's going on.

The only thing I am seeing as an issue is my query

```
$query = "UPDATE reservations
                SET checked_in = CASE 
                WHEN checked_in = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN checked_in = 1 THEN 0 END 
                $where";
```

I am sure it has to do with my `CASE` statement but I can't seem to pinpoint it no matter how much I tinker it.

What is supposed to be happening is this: I get a list of the new `checkins` into an array called `$checkins` and I also get a list of check**ed**ins which is all of those that *were* checked before the POST into an array called `$checkedins`. If they are not in the list of `$checkins` then I add it to `$checkins` array. So `$checkins` now contains all the rows to be checked and unchecked. What my query *should* do is change everything in the array to a 1 that is a 0 and everything that is a 0 to a 1. It is doing the latter. I am asking help for the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I decided to do was split up the queries. I made a `$checkin_where` string and a `$uncheck_where` string. I placed the appropriate `$id`s in each and used two different `UPDATE` queries:

```
//create WHERE clause for new checkins
    $checkin_where = " WHERE id =";
    $uncheck_where = " WHERE id =";
     foreach ($_POST['checkins'] as $id) {
        $checkin_where .= " $id OR id =";
        array_push($checkins, $id);
    }

    //loop through $checkedins[]
    foreach ($checkedins as $id) {
        //if they were checked in before and are now not checked in, add to list
        if (!in_array($id["id"], $checkins))
            $uncheck_where .= " ".$id['id']." OR id =";
    }

    //remove last 8 characters from WHERE clause
    $uncheck_where = substr($uncheck_where, 0, -8);
    $checkin_where = substr($checkin_where, 0, -8);

    if (strlen($checkin_where) > 5)
    {
        echo $query = "UPDATE reservations
                    SET checked_in = 1
                    $checkin_where";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }

    if (strlen($uncheck_where) > 5)
    {
        echo $query = "UPDATE reservations
                    SET checked_in = 0
                    $uncheck_where";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `checked_in` is guaranteed to be zero or one, you can use this little trick to avoid the `CASE altogether:

```
SET checked_in = 1 - checked_in
WHERE ...
```

Expression `1-x` evaluates to `1` when `x` is `0`, and to `0` when `x` is `1`.

Comment: this checks the ones I check that were previously *not* checked but unchecks the ones that *were* checked that I didn't touch.

Comment: @user2690363 Isn't that the same exact thing that your `CASE` statement does? It says "WHEN 0 then 1 WHEN 1 THEN 0`, so that's the same logic, no?

Comment: I just checked and yes you're right. So I guess that means I need to break up the queries?

Comment: Because not necessarily everything that *was* checked needs to be unchecked and that is what that statement does.

Comment: @user2690363 I guess you may want to do that. The question is too long as it is. You may want to explain the logic of checking and un-checking in your edit to explain *what* you want to do, not necessarily *how* you went about doing it.

Comment: Yea, I usually get asked for more context so now when I post I try to give too much rather than too little. If I can't figure it out in a minute or so I will edit. Thanks.